# how to delete particular device's details in server's db?

Tags: android

I am using db for my android application,I am storing user's details andr device id in server's db,when user run my application at first time,I want to delete particular user's details in server db,whenever user uninstall my application in device.How can i implement this scenario in my application.

Thanks

Comment: using phone number may be it is possible

Comment: @Thanks for reply,can u give your suggestion elaborate?

Answer (score 0):

As far as I know, there is no way to know when your app is being uninstalled on Android so I am not sure if you can take any such action.